# Can we replace application with lower version from higher version

Tags: android

Two Android apk with API  One with version name 1.0 and the other with version name 1.1. Can i install 1.0 version on 1.1?

Comment: Kindly Accept/UpVote the answer if you have got your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this,

You have to **uninstall** higher version first and then **install** older version.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

**The higher version needs to be uninstalled before installing any lower version.**

Answer (score 0):

The version name is irrelevant.  Just set the `android:versionCode` for your version named 1.0 to be anything higher than what you used for the version named 1.1.